# Can't apply AppArmor profile on container: "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, containers, apparmor

I am trying to apply the following simple AppArmor profile:

```
#include <tunables/global>

profile docker-profile flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #network,
  #capability,
  #file,
  #umount,
  #ptrace,
  #mount,
  pivot_root,
}
```

When I run `docker run -it --rm --security-opt apparmor=docker-profile alpine` I get the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci
>   runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process
>   caused \"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \\"apparmor
>   failed to apply profile: no such file or directory\\"\"\n".

I tried to reinstall it (based on suggestions [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25488)):

```
rm -rf /etc/apparmor*
apt install apparmor --reinstall
service apparmor restart
service docker restart
```

It didn't help, I am still getting the same error.

Any suggestion what can be the reason and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to register the profile by running `apparmor_parser -r -W docker.profile`.

More information can be found here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo apt-get purge apparmor apparmor-profiles apparmor-utils

sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra vim-addon-manager

reboot
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: this worked for me on Debian 11 bullseye! thanks!

Comment: this worked for me on MxLinux 21

Comment: I'm Running omv6, and something happened when I updated and all the docker container refused to load. I don't know what happened but this fixed it.

Comment: worked for Debian 11 bullseye!!!!!!

Comment: The `vim-addon-manager` is not needed... but it works!

Comment: I was having the same issue on `orange pi+ 2` after installing the docker from `armbian-config` utility, I ran the above commands and things seems to be working for me.