# Docker not working anymore after applying updates to OpenMediaVault

Tags: docker, docker-daemon, openmediavault

After a security update, OpenMediaVault 5 would not let Docker launch stacks.

Logs seems to indicate those problems comes from app-armor refusing the Docker daemon to do its thing....

Ideas ?

I tried to launch Portainer without success.
I tried to reinstall it, without success.
I rebooted a couple of times, without success.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution in [Can't apply AppArmor profile on container: "no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435648/cant-apply-apparmor-profile-on-container-no-such-file-or-directory):

I used:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
sudo apt install apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra
```

Then I rebooted... and Docker works now.